# How exactly do automatic updates work?

Tags: php, automatic-updates

I received an email this morning stating that my Wordpress site had been automatically updated to the latest version. I knew about the feature but I've always wondered exactly how it works.

PHP isn't a permanently-running process: it only runs when requested. So as far as I can tell, Wordpress can only update itself when someone loads a web page. But the update process is not instantaneous, so surely a user visiting the site would have a really slow page load.

Is there a different trick they use for automatic updates? I've searched all over the place but haven't found any explanation.

Comment: Just to be precise it will only update when a new minor or security update is released so for example from 3.8 to 3.8.1 but when 3.9 is released (as a major version update) then you will have to do it manually.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> PHP isn't a permanently-running process: it only runs when requested.
>   So as far as I can tell, Wordpress can only update itself when someone
>   loads a web page. But the update process is not instantaneous, so
>   surely a user visiting the site would have a really slow page load.
>
> Is there a different trick they use for automatic updates? I've
>   searched all over the place but haven't found any explanation.

The system you're looking for here is called "WP Cron". It's a background process system in WordPress that allows events to occur outside of normal processing. They still need a trigger to kick them off, but they don't interfere with page loads because of the background process.

So yes, somebody must load your page. Off in the default-filters.php file, you'll find this line of code:

`add_action( 'init', 'wp_cron' );`

So, on every page load, the wp_cron function runs. This function is over in wp-includes/cron.php and what it does is to check the scheduled events in the database. If there are any processes it needs to run in the background, then it calls the function spawn_cron.

Spawn cron has two possible methods of operation, but the first and most common one is to call the wp_remote_post function to make a connection back to itself, on the URL of wp-cron.php. By making this extra HTTP request, it starts another PHP process to do all the actual work. The request it makes here is non-blocking, with a timeout of 0.01 seconds. So, it doesn't actually get any results here. The purpose of the request is simply to start a new process in the background. After this is done, it simply returns, so the viewing user never has any delays.

The wp-cron.php process is what does the actual work, and the update, and everything else. Lots of processes in WordPress are handled by the cron system. Scheduled post publishing, processing pings, update checks, anything which needs to happen outside the normal flow can be scheduled and then run on an as-needed basis.

But yes, a normal hit to the site must indeed happen to kick off the process. And no, WordPress.org does not contact your site directly to kick things off, your site has to receive some form of traffic to start it up. Any form of traffic will do.

Comment: Is there an API exposed by WordPress, which wp-cron consumes to check if an update is available or not? I am trying to understand the entire anatomy of this process, including any APIs involved, the mode of communication between the two entities e.t.c. Your answer helped, but a little more insight about the points I mentioned would make it even clearer.

Answer (score 17):

Actually, the automatic update is pushed from `wp.org`. The update process still runs on your site, but in the background via `wp-cron`.

When a new minor update is released, the guys at WordPress start to roll out the update. **The actual update process is started after your site checked `wp.org` for updates, an update is theoretically available, and your site is chosen by random to be updated.**

---

> (Thank you @otto for pointing out my wrong wording :) )

---

As every site checks with `wp.org` for new versions (usually twice dayily using `wp-cron`), the rolloutserver knows how many sites need an update.

Then the rollout begins, starting slowly - 1 out of 128 sites gets updated automatically. This is being monitored, and if the successrate indicates no problems with the rollout, more of the sites get the automatic update (usually the next step would be 1 out of 64, and continuing to increase that way) until all automatic updates are delivered.

This enables the developers to stop the rollout if any problems occur, but the last update from `3.8` to `3.8.1` has had a 100% success rate.

The sites selected by the `1 out of 128` is actually random. Well, not really, but if you want to know, it works like this:

The Url of the site needing an update gets hashed using `MD5`. Using just the first three characters of this hash and converting it to `base10`, this results in 4096 possibilities. The update started for sites having a calculated number between 0 and 31 (4096 / 32 = 128).

Okay, i guess it's pretty random after all ;)

In my case, as I run a lot of WordPress sites, the updates took 1 day - was pretty funny to see when all the pages were updated.

Just in case you were wondering :D

btw, [here](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/01/24/3-8-1-auto-update-rollout/) is an article on make.wordpress.org describing the process, as it happened.

Comment: If it's "started by a request from wp.org to your site", how is that secure? Couldn't anyone send a request to your site?

Comment: Actually, I do not know how this is handled technically. But I am sure there are security checks, like a nonce and/or where the request comes from.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! Can you please link to where you found this from, for further study?

Comment: Of course! I updated the answer to show the Link to more people directly.

Comment: I really hope you are wrong about the update being pushed as it will mean that wp.org have the addresses of all the wordpress sites in the world.

Comment: @MarkKaplun this is official WordPress information. Even google knows the adresses of all the WordPress sites in the world ;) So this alone is nothing I am worried about.

Comment: @fischi google can't know what is a wordpress site example.com/he might be a site or a page in example.com. wp.org can know therefor I still hope you are wrong and wherever you read it is wrong.

Comment: @fischi Were did you get the info that wp.org initiates the update from? There is a BIG difference between wp.org initiating the update or the wordpress site checking for updates and then initiating the update itself if wp.org tells it that there are updates.

Comment: What happens when the site wasn't ready during the new releae roll-out (e.g. incorrect file permissions)? Will the site totally miss that particular update and just wait for the next minor release? Or is there something that triggers the update regularly?

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect. The update process is not initiated by WordPress.org to your site. Your site does indeed need to have some form of traffic to kick it off, but WordPress.org does not ping your site directly.

Comment: @otto - the information was not that your site is pinged by wp.org, but the update is initiated if wp.org tells your site that you will receive the update. By searching for updates (automatically) at wp.org they know your site wants one, and decide when this process starts. It was a little unclear, you are right, so thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: Okay, but "started by a request from wp.org to your site" is incorrect. Your site makes the update request, and the response tells you whether there is an update or not. It's not the other way around, your site has to initiate the process.

Answer (score 1):

In very broad terms, when a user visits the site wordpress checks for timer expiry and if an expiry is detected **another** request is sent to the server to "run" the actions associated with the expired event. This is why the user doesn't feel any noticeable delay in page load, as the server is running the actual action (upgrade in this case) in a separate process.

This works but the timing is not very accurate. The more traffic your site has the more accurate it will be.

People that want to get better performance and more accurate timing can block the internal cron "process" wordpress has, and use the OS cron process to trigger the checking of timers.