# How to turn off automatic updates of the WordPress core

Tags: automatic-updates

I have two dozen installations of WordPress on my servers and until my most recent install, I have had to manually update versions (my preferred method). But this morning I received that a notice that this latest install updated to 5.7.2 automatically. I'd like to turn this off but only see a way to toggle minor vs. major updates on the Update screen. There is no mention of updates in wp-config.php, however, there are settings in wp_options that show `auto_update_core_major` is `disabled` (I just did this via the Update screen) and now `auto_update_core_minor` is `enabled`. I searched the "Interwebs" on how to turn this off. Is this the default? and can it only be overridden by wp-config.php or the MySQL command line?

This [thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131334/how-exactly-do-automatic-updates-work) (ibid. #131334) explains some random process, but that doesn't seem very safe and a bit domineering.

Thanks, Brad

**Update:** Best explanation: wpengine.com.au/resources/disable-auto-update

Comment: This was the first result when searching "How to turn off automatic updates of the WordPress core": https://wpengine.com.au/resources/disable-auto-update/ Have you tried that?

Comment: Also, disabling these updates will leave you vulnerable if you don't manually update as soon as you can anyway.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I did read that, but I thought there had to be a simpler solution, e.g., in Settings. Changing code or using a plugin seemed a bit much for the average user. But, I guess that's what it is. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have a cron that checks for updates every night so I can stay on top of updates.

Comment: The "average user" shouldn't need to change this. And why are you running your own cron job when you could just use this feature?

Comment: Good question. I don't want the process automated (testing, etc). It also reminds me to clean up git repos and check general health.

Answer (score 2):

In `wp-config.php` add

```
// Disable all wordpress auto updates. 
define('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true);
define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false);
```

In `functions.php` add

```
// Disable auto plugin updates
add_filter('auto_update_plugin', '__return_false');

// Disable auto theme updates
add_filter('auto_update_theme', '__return_false');
```